# Sylius Customizing Models with error class not found in namespaces

Tags: sylius

I followed the guideline on Sylius site for customizing models:
http://docs.sylius.com/en/1.0/customization/model.html

When I run:

php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

or
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff

Error: The class 'AppBundle\Entity\Country' was not found in the chain configured namespaces

Files added at:
\src\AppBundle\Entity\Country.php
\src\AppBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\Country.orm.yml

Added:

```
sylius_addressing:
    resources:
        country:
            classes:
                model: AppBundle\Entity\Country
```

at:
\app\config\config.yml

And doctrine related settings on config.yml as below:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
    driver: "%database_driver%"
    host: "%database_host%"
    port: "%database_port%"
    dbname: "%database_name%"
    user: "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    server_version: "5.5"
    charset: UTF8

doctrine_migrations:
    dir_name: "%kernel.root_dir%/migrations"
    namespace: Sylius\Migrations
    table_name: sylius_migrations
    name: Sylius Migrations
```

Country.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Sylius\Component\Addressing\Model\Country as BaseCountry;
class Country extends BaseCountry
{
  private $flag;

  public function getFlag(): ?bool
  {
    return $this->flag;
  }

  public function setFlag(bool $flag): void
  {
    $this->flag = $flag;
  }
}
```

(Sylius 1.0 installed on Windows 7)
Tried clear cache and many other methods but no clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed latest version (1.1.6) and it works!

So, should be a bug on 1.0.0 version...

Answer (score 0):

You have an indentation error in config.yml, it should be:

`sylius_addressing:
    resources:
        country:
            classes:
                model: AppBundle\Entity\Country`

(you haven't tab symbol before country)

Comment: Thanks, but just check again, the tab already included. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks, but just check again, the tab already included.

YAML forbid tabs. Use 2 or 4 spaces instead. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19976827/3132684)

Comment: Doctrine doesn't know anything about your Country Entity. Check identation in config.yml for doctrine. I try to reproduce the error on latest Sylius (1.1) following the guide and all working for me. Check my config on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Sn2VuBFY)

Comment: And can you show your `src/AppBundle/Entity/Country.php` file? Is `Country` class extends `Sylius\Component\Addressing\Model\Country` and in `AppBundle\Entity` namespace?

Comment: Added on the original post, pls have a look.

Comment: compared the config, no big diff except:
resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
dir_name: "%kernel.root_dir%/migrations"

Tried changed to yours and no different...

Comment: Try this command: `composer dump-autoload`. If it doesn't help - IDK and need to look at the files as is. Because according to this description everything works (at least for me).

Comment: checked on config again, no:
 - { resource: services.yml }
(and no such file as well)
not sure if it's the different between 1.0.0 and 1.1 version.

Comment: I have installed latest version (1.1.6) and it works!

So, should be a bug on 1.0.0 version...
I thought 1.0.0 would be a stable version so I picked it. Now I've found I was wrong...

Anyway, thanks for your help indeed.