# Could not parse .travis.yml

Tags: docker, travis-ci, aws-ecs

I'm trying to create CI pipeline with GitHub, Travis CI and AWS ECS. When I'm push commit to master branch, I'm getting error in travis CI: 'Could not parse .travis.yml'. I can't figure out, where is the problem. Travis dosen't provide more information about error.

There is a code, which I'm using:

## .travis.yml

```
language: csharp
dist: trusty
sudo: required
mono: none
dotnet: 2.0.0
branches:
    only:
        - master
before_script:
    - chmod -R a+x scripts
script:
    - ./scripts/dotnet-build.sh
    - ./scripts/dotnet-publish.sh
    - ./scripts/docker-publish-travis.sh
```

## dotnet-build.sh

```
 dotnet restore 
 dotnet build
```

## dotnet-publish.sh

```
dotnet publish ./BookMeMobi2 -c Release -o ./bin/Docker
```

## dotnet-publish-travis.sh

```
pip install --user awscli
eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-central-1)
docker build -t bookmemobi2 .
docker ps
docker tag bookmemobi2:latest 601510060817.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bookmemobi2:latest
docker push 601510060817.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bookmemobi2:latest
```

I don't know where is the problem. Could you help me?

Comment: I used to use 4 space tabulation. In yaml file we should use 2 space tabulation. Also, there was a problem with windows end of lines (use UNIX eof).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [yamllint](https://github.com/adrienverge/yamllint), which you can install, or just copy&paste to a [web-based version](http://www.yamllint.com).

With the example in the question, I get:

> (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 7 column 1

There's a tab on line 7. See "https://stackoverflow.com/q/19975954".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case I was using python to launch a couple of scripts. I placed them one after the other with a hyphen at the beginning, exactly as you. So I searched to found out that I could place all of them in one line with "&" between each script and I got rid of the hyphen.

What I had:

```
 script: 
 - python  test_Math_DC.py
 - python test_Math_Moy.py
 - python test_Math_Var.py
 - python test_Math_SQRT.py
```

Changed to :

```
script: python test_Math_DC.py & python test_Math_Moy.py & python test_Math_Var.py & python test_Math_SQRT.py
```

In your case you could try :

```
script: ./scripts/dotnet-build.sh & ./scripts/dotnet-publish.sh & ./scripts/docker-publish-travis.sh
```

or something like this :

```
script: sh ./scripts/dotnet-build.sh & sh ./scripts/dotnet-publish.sh & sh ./scripts/docker-publish-travis.sh
```

And see how it works out.

Comment: In my case, that was a problem with tabulation. I had setup vs code with 4 space tabulation. .Yaml file expect 2 space tabulation.

Answer (score 0):

The travis cli tool has a linter

```
gem install travis
```

However, it only gives warnings for the example. Also, it currently does not work with all features, for example stages.

```
$ travis lint
Warnings for .travis.yml:
[x] unexpected key mono, dropping
[x] unexpected key dotnet, dropping
```