# how to configure and run Reaper to repair cassandra in linux( centos environment)

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, repair, reaper

I'm trying to install and run Reaper 1.4 on my centos VM. And followed the same installation step as in given video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0dub29BgwPI), but still no success in getting reaper started.Can anyone please help  me with proper/complete document. however i have read and followed 
http://cassandra-reaper.io/docs/download/

**Below given is my cassandra-reaper.yaml settings:**

```
segmentCountPerNode: 16
repairParallelism: DATACENTER_AWARE
repairIntensity: 0.9
scheduleDaysBetween: 7
repairRunThreadCount: 15
hangingRepairTimeoutMins: 30
storageType: cassandra
enableCrossOrigin: true
incrementalRepair: false
blacklistTwcsTables: false
enableDynamicSeedList: true
repairManagerSchedulingIntervalSeconds: 10
activateQueryLogger: false
jmxConnectionTimeoutInSeconds: 5
useAddressTranslator: false
# purgeRecordsAfterInDays: 30
# numberOfRunsToKeepPerUnit: 10
jmxPorts:
        #127.0.0.1: 7100
        #10.X.X.X: 7199
        #127.0.0.2: 7200
        #127.0.0.3: 7300
        #127.0.0.4: 7400
        #127.0.0.5: 7500
        #127.0.0.6: 7600
        #127.0.0.7: 7700
        #127.0.0.8: 7800

jmxAuth:
        username: *****
        password: *****

server:
  type: default
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8080
      bindHost: 0.0.0.0
  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8081
      bindHost: 0.0.0.0
  requestLog:
    appenders: []
cassandra:
  clusterName: "dc1"
  contactPoints: ["10.X.X.1","10.X.X.2","10.X.X.3","10.X.X.4","10.X.X.5"]
  #contactPoints: ["127.0.0.1"]
  keyspace: "reaper_db"
  loadBalancingPolicy:
    type: tokenAware
    shuffleReplicas: true
    subPolicy:
      type: dcAwareRoundRobin
      localDC:
      usedHostsPerRemoteDC: 0
      allowRemoteDCsForLocalConsistencyLevel: false
  authProvider:
    type: plainText
    username: cass
    password: cass
  ssl:
    type: jdk

autoScheduling:
  enabled: false
  initialDelayPeriod: PT15S
  periodBetweenPolls: PT10M
  timeBeforeFirstSchedule: PT5M
  scheduleSpreadPeriod: PT6H
  excludedKeyspaces:
    - keyspace1
    - keyspace2
accessControl:
  sessionTimeout: PT10M
  shiro:
    iniConfigs: ["classpath:shiro.ini"]
```

**log from /var/log/cassandra-reaper/reaper.log**

```
INFO   [main] i.c.ReaperApplication - initializing runner thread pool with 15 threads
INFO   [main] i.c.ReaperApplication - initializing storage of type: cassandra
INFO   [main] c.d.d.core - DataStax Java driver 3.5.0 for Apache Cassandra
INFO   [main] c.d.d.c.GuavaCompatibility - Detected Guava >= 19 in the classpath, using modern compatibility layer
INFO   [main] c.d.d.c.ClockFactory - Using native clock to generate timestamps.
INFO   [main] c.d.d.c.NettyUtil - Found Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, using it
INFO   [main] o.a.s.c.ReflectionBuilder - An instance with name 'authc' already exists.  Redefining this object as a new instance of type org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.PassThruAuthenticationFilter
```

**log from /var/log/cassandra-reaper.err**

```
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:415)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:226)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseBlockMappingValue.produce(ParserImpl.java:586)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.getEvent(ParserImpl.java:168)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLParser.nextToken(YAMLParser.java:347)
        ... 11 more
ls: cannot access server/target/cassandra-reaper-*.jar: No such file or directory
io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationParsingException: /etc/cassandra-reaper/cassandra-reaper.yaml has an error:
  * Malformed YAML at line: 27, column: 11; while scanning for the next token; found character  '\t' that cannot start any token;  in 'reader', line 27, column 1:
        clusterName: "dc1"
    ^
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 26, column: 10]

        at io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationParsingException$Builder.build(ConfigurationParsingException.java:279)
        at io.dropwizard.configuration.BaseConfigurationFactory.build(BaseConfigurationFactory.java:96)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.parseConfiguration(ConfiguredCommand.java:126)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:74)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
        at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)
        at io.cassandrareaper.ReaperApplication.main(ReaperApplication.java:99)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.error.MarkedYAMLException: while scanning for the next token; found character        '\t' that cannot start any token;  in 'reader', line 27, column 1:
        clusterName: "dc1"
    ^
```

Comment: can you check whats the failure ? the logs are under "/var/log/cassandra-reaper.err" and "/var/log/cassandra-reaper.log"

Comment: @Mpadikka : Added logs in above section, since logs were too big. Can you please check the logs & give  me some idea.

Comment: * Malformed YAML at line: 27, column: 11; while scanning for the next token; found character  '\t' that cannot start any token;  in 'reader', line 27, column 1:
        clusterName: "dc1"

seems just the text editing issue  - you copy the contents of yaml to a notepad++ and make sure to use proper tab spacing on the line starting of clusterName and going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - Malformed YAML at line: 27, column: 11; while scanning for the next token; found character  '\t' that cannot start any token;  in 'reader', line 27, column 1:
>         clusterName: "dc1"

You need to remove any tab whitespaces in your yaml file and replace it with 4 spaces instead.

See the answer here for why this is common when manipulating YAML files.
[A YAML file cannot contain tabs as indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975954/a-yaml-file-cannot-contain-tabs-as-indentation)