# Docker-compose: Issue while running the spring boot enabled and spring cloud config application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, spring-cloud-config

I want to run the Spring Boot enabled and spring cloud config project to deploy to Docker. The below is the docker-compose.yml file. But I'm getting the following error while running the file.

**Error:**

```
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 4, column 4
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 48, column 5
```

Below is my **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
    version: '3'

    services:
          discovery:
            image: pl.app.service/discovery-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
            ports:
              - 8061:8061
          config:
            image: pl.app.service/config-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
            volumes:
              - ./config-data:/config-data
            environment:
               - JAVA_OPTS=
               -DEUREKA_SERVER=http://discovery:8761/eureka
               -Dspring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=/config-data
             depends_on:
              - discovery
             ports:
              - 8088:8088

      proxy-service:
        image: pl.app.service/proxy-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        environment:
          - JAVA_OPTS=
            -DEUREKA_SERVER=http://discovery:8761/eureka
        depends_on:
          - discovery
          - config
        ports:
            -8060:8060

      employee-service:
        image: pl.app.service/employee-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        environment:
          - JAVA_OPTS=
            -DEUREKA_SERVER=http://discovery:8761/eureka
            -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
        restart: on-failure
        depends_on:
          - discovery
          - config
        ports:
            -8090:8090

      department-service:
          image: pl.app.service/organization-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        environment:
          - JAVA_OPTS=
            -DEUREKA_SERVER=http://discovery:8761/eureka
            -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
        restart: on-failure
        depends_on:
          - discovery
          - config
        ports:
            -8091:8091

       organization-service:
          image: pl.app.service/organization-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        environment:
          - JAVA_OPTS=
            -DEUREKA_SERVER=http://discovery:8761/eureka
            -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
        restart: on-failure
        depends_on:
          - discovery
          - config
        ports:
            -8092:8092
```

I have tried multiple indentations changes for docker-compose.yml file.

The mentioned services are already built by maven. Need help in running the docker composer for the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple errors.

1. Make sure that you only use spaces for indentation (instead of tabs). If you are interested why tabs don't work within yaml files have a look at [A YAML file cannot contain tabs as indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975954/a-yaml-file-cannot-contain-tabs-as-indentation)
2. put your ports into strings (e.g. `- "8060:8060"`instead of `- 8060:8060`)
3. I think you are misusing environment variables. They should/must look like e.g.:

`environment:
   - JAVA_OPTS
   - EUREKA_SERVER=http://discovery:8761/eureka
   - ANOTHER_ENV_VARIABLE=/config-data`

Have a look at the docs for details: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

After fixing your docker-compose.yml you can validate your file by running `docker-compose config` inside of the directory where your docker-compose.yml is located.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have done the changes as you mentioned above. But I am still getting the error for below two lines
 `-DEUREKA_SERVER=http://discovery:8761/eureka/
     -Dspring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations="/config-data"`

Error is:
` ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a simple key
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 13, column 6
could not find expected ':'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 14, column 6
'

Comment: Yes, this is what I mentioned under `3.`. You can't use environment variables like that: `-DEUREKA_SERVER=http://discovery:8761/eureka/`. It has to be `- EUREKA_SERVER=http://discovery:8761/eureka`. Have a look at the syntax. There needs to be a space between the `-` and the variable name. Please be aware of the fact that you are defining environment variables here. It seems like you are confounding environment variables and java system properties (-D) here.

Comment: Once again thank you. The last error I am getting is :  ERROR: 'The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.discovery: 'config' ' . Please let me know how to configure the config option.

Comment: Please have another look at your indentations. `config` is not an option but the name of a service (like `discovery`, `organization-service`, ...). It has to be on the same level of indentation as the other services. As the error says docker interprets `config` as an option named config (which does not exist). But instead config is the name of a service.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am really thankful to you as yours response is quick and its fixes the issues !!!
 While Running the 'docker-compose up -d'  I am getting error like

ERROR: Get https://pl.app.service/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup pl.piomin.service on 10.168.57.53:53: no such host

Please help me on this. Thank you in advance !! :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm afraid I have no idea about the newest error you posted. Anyways: As your newest problem is no longer related to syntax errors regarding your docker-compose.yml (but to your specific setup) I would advise you to open a new separate question for this most current error when running `docker-compose up` (with all information you can give that might help others to help you, like where does that `ping` come frome)