# Cant install stable version of Flare error in first line

Tags: flutter, flare

Fresh flutter project, getting error when adding "flare_flutter: ^1.5.1", to pubspec.yaml.

i have flutter v1.5.4-hotfix.2

tried the dev branch of flare

in my .yaml file

```
dependencies:

  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  flare_flutter: ^1.5.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

my error

```
[funke_aldri] flutter packages get
Running "flutter packages get" in funke_aldri...                
Error on line 1, column 1 of ..\..\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flare_flutter-1.5.1\pubspec.yaml: Unexpected character.

  ╷

1 │ 

  ╵
pub get failed (65)
exit code 65
```

Comment: You are most certain that you have the correct indentation? `*.yml` files are really strict in this regard! Another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19976827/3266152) has touched how to handle these files

Comment: I swapped out 'flare_flutter: ^1.5.1' with 'firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+6' , then the error disappeared. i'm confused, changed it back to, and the error is back. Pls help

Comment: The error is in the library itself according to your error message. Why are you at the dev branch of flare?