# Go YAML unmarshal doesn't decode all the object structure to a generic interface. Any ideas why?

Tags: go, yaml, unmarshalling

Why wouldn't the following `Go` program work? The map is empty after the Unmarshal. Is there any changes that I could do to deserialize this correctly? Or should I end up using `yaml.Node`?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

func main() {
    empYaml := `
      employees:
        - id: 11
          name: Irshad
          department: IT
          designation: Product Manager
          address:
            city: Mumba
            state: Maharashtra
            country: India
    `

    var result map[string]interface{}
    yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(empYaml), &result)

    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Play URL: https://play.golang.org/p/tG44j15mNjH

Comment: Do not ignore the return value of Unmarshal, it'll tell you what's wrong with the input.

Comment: Never ignore errors. *sigh*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I check the error from the call to `yaml.Unmarshal` I see the error:

> 2009/11/10 23:00:00 yaml: line 2: found character that cannot start any token

Looks like this may be due to tab characters in the content since YAML [forbids tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19976827/2081133).

Remove all tab characters from the YAML content and you should be in good shape. I get the following output:

```
map[employees:[map[address:map[city:Mumba country:India state:Maharashtra] department:IT designation:Product Manager id:11 name:Irshad]]]
```

Comment: Just did the same based on Burak's comment. Thanks!