# How to unmarshal a yaml array?

Tags: go, yaml

I have next yaml, if I validate it in [online yaml website](http://www.yamllint.com/), it said it's valid:

```
- {"foo": "1", "bar": "2"}
```

Then, I write a code to parse the value `1` and `2` from this yaml as next:

**test.go**:

```
package main
import "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
import "fmt"

type Config struct {
    Foo string
    Bar string
}

type Configs struct {
    Cfgs []Config `foobar`
}

func main() {
    //var data = `
    //  foobar:
    //  - foo: 1
    //    bar: 2
    //`
    var data = `
      - foo: 1
        bar: 2
    `

    source := []byte("foobar:" + data)
    var configs Configs
    err := yaml.Unmarshal(source, &configs)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("--- configs:\n%v\n\n", configs)
    fmt.Println(configs.Cfgs[0].Foo)
    fmt.Println(configs.Cfgs[0].Bar)
}
```

**It works ok as next:**

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/20210810$ go run test.go
--- configs:
{[{1 2}]}

1
2
```

**What's the problem?**

You could see I made a workaround here as next to add special `foobar` key before the original yaml, then I could use `type Configs struct` to unmarshal it:

From

```
- foo: 1
  bar: 2
```

to

```
foobar:
- foo: 1
  bar: 2
```

So, if I don't use the workaround to add a prefix `foobar:`, how could I directly parse `- {"foo": 1, "bar": 2}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your `YAML` data is an array, unmarshal it to an array of `Config` structure.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Config struct {
    Foo string
    Bar string
}

func main() {
    var configs []Config

    var data = `
      - foo: 1
        bar: 2
    `

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &configs)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(configs)
}
```

**Output:**

```
[{1 2}]
```

Try on - [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/W_XRAzAFZw6)

Comment: Great, such a simple solution I missed, thank you~

Answer (score 1):

Since the question has already been answered, I thought I might add something to the discussion:

```golang
    var data = `
      - foo: 1
        bar: 2
    `
```

The data variable here, the way you wrote it, **will** include the indentation at the start of each line.

The extra indentation here WILL be passed into `yaml.Unmarshal()` alongside all the actual yaml data, which can mess things up since **`gofmt` formats your code to use TAB as indentation** and **TAB indentation is forbidden in yaml** (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19976827/7509248).

If you use tab as indentation in yaml, an error like this will be thrown when trying to unmarshal it:

```
yaml: line 1: found a tab character that violates indentation
```

Preferably, you want to load `data` from a separate file to avoid such issue.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Config struct {
    Foo string
    Bar string
}

func main() {
    var configs []Config

    source, err := ioutil.ReadFile("config.yaml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("failed reading config file: %v\n", err)
    }

    err = yaml.Unmarshal(source, &configs)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("config:\n%+v\n", configs)
}
```

config.yaml:

```yaml
- foo: 1
  bar: 2
```

output:

```
config:
[{Foo:1 Bar:2}]
```

Comment: ``echo -e "func main() {\n  t := `\n    foo`\n}" | gofmt | tr ' \t' '•↹'`` shows that gofmt does *not* replace the space indentation inside of the backtick string, so this is not a problem. Besides, it is best practice to put the input in the code sample for a StackOverflow question so that others do not need to set up a file system to execute the code.